# vba conditional formatting with Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format cells in a range using VBA. My goal is that every time a cell is selected, every cell which holds the same text will be formatted.

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal t As Range)    
   Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
   Range("B2:K29").Select
   Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=t.Value, _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
   With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .TintAndShade = 0
   End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that every time I select a cell, **all** the cells in the range are formatted (and not just the ones which have the same text as in the selected cell).

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and setting this format to see if your code is OK ?

Comment: Have you looked at the conditional formatting window?  What is it displaying as the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = Target.Cells(1)
    Me.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then

     With Me.Range("B2:K29").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, _
                       String:=c.Value, TextOperator:=xlContains)
         With .Font
          .Bold = True
          .Italic = False
          .TintAndShade = 0
         End With
     End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want done is already provided by Tim so select his answer.
I'll just post this as another approach for anyone who might stumble in this question.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        With Me.Range("A1").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, _
                     String:=Target.Value, TextOperator:=xlContains)
            With .Font
                .Bold = True
                .Italic = False
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .ModifyAppliesToRange Me.Range("B2:K29")
        End With
    End If
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```